# Run Mac App with CloudKit connected to the Production environment

Tags: xcode, cloudkit, cloudkit-environments

Has anyone succeeded to run a Developer ID signed Mac App with CloudKit and with access to the Production environment, using Xcode 8 beta 3? According to [this diagram](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html) of Apple it should be possible, but all my attempts lead to crashes. What are the exact steps to follow?

My attempts until now includes the use of a "Mac DirectDistribution" Provisioning Profile that points to an App ID with CloudKit enabled and with access to an iCloud Container.

My CloudKit enabled-app works perfectly with a standard App Store configuration, but I want to test it with a Production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless experiments I found the following working solution to test CloudKit on the Mac with Production data, using Xcode 7.3:

1. In your App project, choose Developer ID in Targets > Identity > Signing
2. In the Entitlements file add a new line with key "com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment" with value "Production"
3. Run the App (debug modus)

Export the app to an Archive, choose Export and select "Export as a Mac Application" to produce a Developer ID-based release version.

The steps are more or less the same if you use Xcode 8, but you have the extra option to disable the App Sandbox.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following entry to your entitlement plist *and* do a clean build (shift+command k).  No other action is needed: (string to copy: `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment`)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Mac the easiest way is to just after Archive click Distribute App then choose Development and click next then choose your iCloud Environment (Production/Test) and save the app wherever you want. This version will access your production iCloud.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfJnk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfYFq.png)